# Data filter with calendar dates range

Tags: javascript, filter, calendar

I'm using [PickMeUp](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp) calendar to filter the events list based on user date pick.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkpmczte/1/

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Here's an excerpt:

```js
let startDay;
let endDay;
let result;

pickmeup(element);
element.addEventListener("pickmeup-change", function(e) {
  startDay = e.detail.formatted_date[0];
  endDay = e.detail.formatted_date[1];

  result = data.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.date >= startDay && obj.date <= endDay;
  });
  getDay();
});

let getDay = () => {
  return startDay === endDay ?
    console.log(startDay) :
    console.log(`${startDay} - ${endDay}`);
};

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

But it turns back an empty array...

I would appreciate any kind of help :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had a typo in date format. I used dashes when I should've used slashes.